# How to set the path for userpref.blend file?

Tags: python, import, blend-files

After compiling Blender as a Python module I realized that `userpref.blend` does not exist in `~/.config/blender/2.79/config`. I want to use a `userpref.blend` file that I have on my desktop computer (when using Blender with the GUI). So I wonder how can one manually set the path to `userpref.blend` file using Blender's Python API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the environmental variable `BLENDER_USER_CONFIG` would do the job. So Blender assumes the path to the `userpref.blend` file would be `BLENDER_USER_CONFIG/userpref.blend`